# Record the number of iterations in a for loop into a Matlab table

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop

I am trying to keep a track of all the calculations happening under 3 *for loops*. The data is too big therefore it is hard to keep the track of the data. Hence, I would like to construct a table which will record the number of iterations taking place inside every *for loop*.

The code:

```
for i = 1:4
    % Calculations
    i
    for j = 1:3
        % Calculations
        j
        for k = 1:3
            % Calculations
            k
        end
    end
end
```

So, the tabular output which I am expecting is like this,

[image]

Can anybody please help me in achieving this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following code, where you declare the dimension of each loop at the beginning, and allocate a `track` matrix.

```
ni=3
nj=4
nk=5

track = zeros(3,ni*nj*nk);

offset = 1
for i = 1:ni
    % Calculations
    i
    for j = 1:nj
        % Calculations
        j
        for k = 1:nk
            % Calculations
            k
            track(1,offset) = i;
            track(2,offset) = j;
            track(3,offset) = k;
            offset = offset + 1;
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: How can I write the headings for the matrix `track`? I tried something like this:                                                                                                    `[m, n] = size(track);
for i=1:n
    track{i} = ['K = ' num2str(i)];
end
for i=1:m
    track{i} = ['n =' num2str(i)];
end`

Answer (score 2):

You could use `ndgrid` to create all permutations of your `i`, `j`, and `k` values and then have a single `for` loop that loops through all permutations.

```
[ii, jj, kk] = ndgrid(1:4, 1:3, 1:3);

% Pre-allocate your results matrix
results = zeros(size(ii));

for n = 1:numel(ii)
    % Do calculation with ii(n), jj(n), kk(n)
    results(n) = ii(n) + jj(n) + kk(n);
end
```

Now if you want to know what the `ii`, `jj`, or `kk` values were for a particular entry in `results`, you can just index into all variables the same way.

```
result_of_interest = results(100);
i_of_interest = ii(100);
j_of_interest = jj(100);
k_of_interest = kk(100);
```

If you really need tabular output, you can transform `ii`, `jj`, and `kk` into your table.

```
data = cat(2, ii(:), jj(:), kk(:))';
```